# Repeated option pricing with Sobol Sequence (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, simulation

Trying to calculate the variance of a European option using repeated trial (instead of 1 trial). I want to compare the variance using the standard randn function and the sobolset. I'm not quite sure how to draw repeated samples from the latter.

Generating from randn is easy:

```
num_steps = 100;
num_paths = 10;
z = rand(num_steps, mum_paths); % 100 paths, for 10 trials
```

Once I have this, I can loop through all the 10 columns of the z matrix, and can also repeat the experiment many times, as the randn function will provide a new random variable set everytime.

```
for exp_num = 1: 20
    for col = 1: 10
        price_vec = z(:, col);
    end
end
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this with the sobolset. I understand I can create a matrix of dimensions to start with (say 100* 10). I can loop through as above through all the columns for the first experiment. However, when I try the next experiment (#2), the loop starts from the beginning and all the numbers are the same. Meaning I don't get any variation in my pricing. It seems I will need to find a way to randomize the column selection at the start of every experiment number. Is there a better way to do this??

```
data1 = sobolset(1000, 'Skip', 1000, 'Leap', 100)
data2 = net(test1, 10)

    for exp_num = 1: 20
% how do I change the start of the column selection here, so that the next data3 is different from %the one in the previous exp_num?
        for col = 1:10
             data3(:, col) = data(2:, col)
             % perform calculations
         end
    end
```

I hope this is making sense....
Thanks for the help!

Update: 8/21
I tried the following:

```
num_runs = 100
num_samples = 1000

for j = 1: num_runs
for i = 1 : num_samples
 
            sobol_set = sobolset(num_samples,'Skip',j*50,'Leap',1e2);
            sobol_set = net(sobol_set, 5);
            sobol_seq = sobol_set(:, i)';
            z_uncorr = norminv(sobol_seq, 0, 1)
            % do pricing with z_uncorr through some function F
end
end
```

After generating 100 prices (through some function F, mentioned above), I find that the variance of the 100 prices is higher than that I get from the standard pseudo random numbers. This should not be the case. I think I'm still not sampling correctly from the sobolset. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I understand correctly then you can simply do another `randn` call after `for exp_num = 1:20`. (`data(2:,col)` is not valid MATLAB syntax.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's a typo in my code (corrected in Matlab). I did try something similar to what you suggested, but I find that the variance of pricing from sobol sequence is the same as the one with randn! I'm definitely not coding it right.